# Creating a collection of nested resources in roar-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-roar

I am trying to create new objects with a collection of nested resources. When I POST my json, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: FormLabel(#70306552439440) expected, got Hash(#70306480154920)
```

Here's my code:

```
# form.rb
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :form_labels
  validates_presence_of :name
end

# form_label.rb
class FormLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  validates_presence_of :form
  validates_presence_of :text
end

# form_representer.rb
module FormRepresenter
  include Roar::JSON
  property :id
  property :name
  collection :form_labels
end

# form_label_representer.rb
module FormLabelRepresenter
  include Roar::JSON
  property :text  
end

# form_controller.rb
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  include Roar::Rails::ControllerAdditions
  def create
    form = Form.new
    consume!(form)
    respond_with(form)
  end
```

When I debug, these are the params:

```
0> params
=> {"name"=>"Address", "form_labels"=>[{"text"=>"foo"}], "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"forms", "action"=>"create", "form"=>{"name"=>"Address"}}
```

and the error is:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: FormLabel(#70237358584300) expected, got Hash(#70237286721880)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line:

```
collection :form_labels
```

It needs to be:

```
collection :form_labels, decorator: FormLabelRepresenter, class: FormLabel
```

See https://github.com/apotonick/roar-rails/issues/125#issuecomment-172175231